# How to apply a tailwindCSS transition to only a single property (border-color instead of everything-color)?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I want that when I change the color of the border of an input the transition is smooth, but not when I change the color of the text.
Now, the transition-color class of tailwind css changes the following properties:

```
transition-property: color, background-color, border-color, text-decoration-color, fill, stroke;
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
transition-duration: 150ms;
```

How can I make the "transition-property" attribute contain only "border-color"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve that using the `Arbitrary values` like this :

```
<input type="text" class="m-4 border-2 border-red-500 p-4 transition-[border-color]" placeholder="some text" />
```

the `transition-[border-color]` will be generated as :

```
.transition-\[border-color\] {
  transition-property: border-color;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition-duration: 150ms;
}
```

[image: the generated CSS - https://play.tailwindcss.com/FJ5PRMh11H]